# grid system Boostrap 4 - inline

Tags: css, html, grid, bootstrap-4

I want that the input fiels are in the same line. But I don't know what am I doing wrong. Can somebody help me? I am using Bootstrap 4.

This is how I wanted it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfIPJ.jpg)

html code

```
<body>

  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div id="content">
            <h1>Contact Page</h1>
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <hr>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 offset-md-3">
            <form class="form-group">
              <div class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
              </div>              
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <form class="form-group">
              <div class="form-inline">
                 <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
              </div>              
            </form>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check your other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Add **"form-row"** or **"row"** in your code.*

```
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

**OR**

```
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure you form.
- Use one  tag for this form. Do Not use for every input a form tag.
- delete the div with class form-inline.
- Add class form-inline to div with class="col-md-6 offset-md-3".

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="container">
  <form>
      <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
             <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
     </div>
 </form>  
 </div>
```

Row or form-row doesn't really matter. Form-row changes the gutter. It's to your own preference.

Comment: Hi @mlite. Thx for your help!

When I try it for my code, than it is not centered, instead it is on the left side. What's the problem?